# Trying to subclass UITableViewCell on Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a problem when trying to subclass UITableViewCell and creating a xib file that correspond to this class X I have.
The steps I did was the same as always.

1. Created a XIB files that has only a UITableViewCell in it and this widget is conformed to my class X.
2. Created a new .swift file that actually defines the X class, subclassing and everything
3. then instantiated the class like this:

   var cell = X()

   It craches right there. My traceback looks like this [image: traceback]

I don't have a clue of what this is.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

The only thing I see in the console at the time of the crash is this:

```
2014-06-24 04:06:51.715 ChemConverter[2261:94363] SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
```

which I don't think it's relevant.

**EDIT 2:**

Declared cell like this

```
var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? UITableViewCell
```

and it worked!

Comment: @BryanChen none. It guides me to the most top-level in the stacktrace and keeps me there.

Comment: crashes always have reason, check console output window

Comment: @BryanChen see edit 1, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an error message or much code to go by, what would happen if you declared your cell variable as optional? Would it crash then? Also, shouldn't you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(...) to get a reference to your cell?

Comment: thought it didn't work at first. But after that, I got another error which has nothing to do with this question. Thanks